# Save data from parameters before validation happens in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form with hidden fields which gets values from parameters. When I first go to the form page my url looks like that:

```html
http://localhost:3000/requests/new?parent_request_id=1&patient_id=1
```

so I have parent_request_id and patient_id parameters. And my hidden_fields get these values.

When user submits the form and in case if validation is not passed user is being returned to the same page with errors messages. The problem is that those parameters in url disappear so hidden fields are empty.

How can I save those parameters. Or is there any better way of sending variables between views?

EDIT:
My controller code:

```html
# requests_controller.rb 
# POST /requests
  # POST /requests.json
  def create
    @request = Request.new(request_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @request.save
        format.html { redirect_to @request, notice: 'Request was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @request }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @request.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


private

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def request_params
      params.require(:request).permit(:description, :diagnos, :payed, :price, :doctor_id, :patient_id, :parent_request_id)
    end
```

and my form:

```html
<div class="form">
  <h1>Данные по обращению</h1>
<%= form_for(@request) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'layouts/error_messages', object: @request %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :parent_request_id, value: params[:parent_request_id] %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :patient_id, value: params[:patient_id] %>

  <% if can? :manage, :all %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label 'Лечащий врач' %>
        <%= f.collection_select(:doctor_id, User.where(role:'doctor'),:id,:name,{include_blank:'-не выбрано-'}, class:'select2') %>
      </div><br>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Описание' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Первичный диагноз' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :diagnos %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Стоимость' %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :price %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Добавить данные', class:'button tiny' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your controller code and your form please.

Comment: @japed i edited my post

Comment: I assume the new action is just `@request = Request.new`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this in your controller

```
class RequestsController
  def new
    @request = Request.new(parent_request_id: params[:parent_request_id],
    patient_id: params[:patient_id])
  end

  def create
    @request = Request.new(request_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @request.save
        format.html { redirect_to @request, notice: 'Request was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @request }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @request.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

end
```

And have your view as simply

```
<%= form_for(@request) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'layouts/error_messages', object: @request %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :parent_request_id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :patient_id %>
<% end %>
```

You will have bound the attributes to the request object in the new action, so they'll be there if the validation fails and won't be set to the parameters which would be nil.

Comment: parameters still disappear from url

Comment: Yeah, it won't have the parameters in the url anymore but they will get posted with the form and will be saved across the new and create actions.